# Can my RichEdit Control contain clickable links?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, mfc

I want to display a series of strings to an Edit Control or Rich Edit 2.0 Control. After that, I want some of the text displayed to be underlined and in blue. These underlined texts can then be clicked to open another dialog or some sort.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rich Edit 2.0 only supports [Automatic RichEdit Hyperlinks](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/murrays/2009/08/31/automatic-richedit-hyperlinks/) while Rich Edit 4.1 and newer (msftedit.dll) supports [Friendly Name Hyperlinks](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/murrays/2009/09/24/richedit-friendly-name-hyperlinks/).

You *can* emulate friendly name hyperlinks in Rich Edit 2.0 by using a combination of the `CFE_LINK` and `CFE_HIDDEN` [character formatting flags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787883(v=vs.85).aspx). Mark the text with `CFE_LINK` and hide the URL by applying `CFE_HIDDEN`. Handle the [`EN_LINK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787970(v=vs.85).aspx) notification to react on clicks. At this point you would have to do some parsing to extract the hidden URL from the rich text.

Alternatively just use `CFE_LINK` for the text and use a `std::map` to map text to URLs. This will work as long as there is a 1:1 mapping of text to URL.

**Edit:** I just noted that you just want "to open another dialog" when a link is clicked, so just applying `CFE_LINK` should be good enough in your case.

**Edit 2:** If you don't need to display formatted text and you also don't need scrolling, I suggest to use the [SysLink control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760706(v=vs.85).aspx). Links displayed by the SysLink control have better accessibility than links in the RichEdit control. The former supports the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key to navigate through the individual links whereas the latter does not.

## Implementing Friendly Name Hyperlinks (Rich Edit 4.1+)

**Disclaimer:** The following code has been tested under Win 10 with creators update. I haven't found time yet to test it under older OS versions.

- In the `InitInstance()` method of your `CWinApp`-derived class, call `AfxInitRichEdit5()` if your version of Visual Studio supports it. Otherwise call `LoadLibraryW(L"msftedit.dll")`.
- Make sure the richedit control uses the right window class. The resource editor creates a RichEdit 2.0 by default. You need to manually edit the .rc file using a text editor and replace `RichEdit20A` or `RichEdit20W` by `RichEdit50W`. The `W` stands for the Unicode version of the control.
- Call `CRichEditCtrl::StreamIn()` to insert the RTF containing the hyperlink(s). In the following I provide a helper function `StreamInRtf()` that simplifies the task of streaming a string into the control:

  ```
  struct StreamInRtfCallbackData
  {
      char const* pRtf;
      size_t size;
  };

  DWORD CALLBACK StreamInRtfCallback( DWORD_PTR dwCookie, LPBYTE pbBuff, LONG cb, LONG *pcb )
  {
      StreamInRtfCallbackData* pData = reinterpret_cast<StreamInRtfCallbackData*>( dwCookie );

      // Copy the number of bytes requested by the control or the number of remaining characters
      // of the source buffer, whichever is smaller.
      size_t sizeToCopy = std::min<size_t>( cb, pData->size );
      memcpy( pbBuff, pData->pRtf, sizeToCopy );

      *pcb = sizeToCopy;

      pData->pRtf += sizeToCopy;
      pData->size -= sizeToCopy;

      return 0;
  }

  DWORD StreamInRtf( CRichEditCtrl& richEdit, char const* pRtf, size_t size = -1, bool selection = false )
  {
      StreamInRtfCallbackData data;
      data.pRtf = pRtf;
      data.size = ( size == -1 ? strlen( pRtf ) : size );

      EDITSTREAM es;
      es.dwCookie    = reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>( &data );
      es.dwError     = 0;
      es.pfnCallback = StreamInRtfCallback;

      int flags = SF_RTF | ( selection ? SFF_SELECTION : 0 );

      richEdit.StreamIn( flags, es );

      return es.dwError;
  }
  ```

  Example usage (using a raw string literal here to make the RTF more readable):

  ```
  StreamInRtf( m_richedit, 
  R"({\rtf1
  {\field{\*\fldinst {HYPERLINK "https://www.stackoverflow.com" }}{\fldrslt {stackoverflow}}}\par
  Some other text\par
  })" );
  ```
- To handle clicks you need to enable `EN_LINK` notifications for the richedit control, e. g.:

  ```
  m_richedit.SetEventMask( m_richedit.GetEventMask() | ENM_LINK );
  ```

  Add a handler for `EN_LINK` to your message map:

  ```
  BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyDialog, CDialog)
      ON_NOTIFY( EN_LINK, IDC_RICHEDIT1, OnLink )
  END_MESSAGE_MAP()
  ```

  Define the event handler method to handle mouse clicks and the return key:

  ```
  void CMyDialog::OnLink( NMHDR* pnm, LRESULT* pResult )
  {
      ENLINK* pnml = reinterpret_cast<ENLINK*>( pnm );

      if(   pnml->msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN || 
          ( pnml->msg == WM_KEYDOWN && pnml->wParam == VK_RETURN ) )
      {
          CString url;
          m_richedit.GetTextRange( pnml->chrg.cpMin, pnml->chrg.cpMax, url );
          AfxMessageBox( L"URL: \"" + url + L"\"" );

          *pResult = 1; // message handled
      }

      *pResult = 0;  // enable default processing
  }
  ```
- Beginning with Windows 8, the control can show a tooltip that displays the URL of the link under the mouse cursor. This feature can be enabled by sending the `EM_SETEDITSTYLE` message to the control:

  ```
  DWORD style = SES_HYPERLINKTOOLTIPS | SES_NOFOCUSLINKNOTIFY;
  m_richedit.SendMessage( EM_SETEDITSTYLE, style, style );
  ```

  In case you are missing the defines, here they are:

  ```
  #ifndef SES_HYPERLINKTOOLTIPS
      #define SES_HYPERLINKTOOLTIPS   8
  #endif
  #ifndef SES_NOFOCUSLINKNOTIFY
      #define SES_NOFOCUSLINKNOTIFY   32
  #endif
  ```

Comment: I'll get around to testing this, as soon as i figure out how to append text to my richeditbox...

Comment: I'll need to format the text actually - different colors. And it'll be a generated list too.

Comment: I've implemented basically the same in the plain WinAPI. Win 10 works perfectly, including hyperlink auto tooltip. Win 7 is somewhat weird: the link is not highlighted in the text, but it works! That is, the cursor is changed to "hand", and notification is sent. The tooltips are not supported.

Comment: @lariona Confirmed. For Win 7 you have to set formatting of the link so it actually appears like a link.

Comment: A simpler alternative for setting text from RTF string is by [EM_SETTEXTEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774284) message (there must be an MFC equivalent but I'm not an expert here). It recognizes plain text from rich, and does not require any callback routine. The EM_STREAMIN (CRichEditCtrl::StreamIn) is probably intended mainly for reading from files.

Comment: I wonder what is the best/easiest way to create an RTF string with basic formatting and links. WordPad is very limited - it does not even contain links (it supports them, but cannot create). Word can do anything, but it creates the file of such size, that using it as RTF string is practically impossible.

Comment: @lariona I usually build them from scratch, looking up the individual RTF tokens from the reference. I have also written a function to escape plain text for use in RTF stream. For links I have a function that converts a simpler, custom syntax like `<link someURL "link text">` into the RTF link syntax which is too hard to remember.

Comment: @zett42: I'm working on something similar and  I have my URL in a string (string str = "https://www.stackoverflow.com") and I wanted to use my str in  StreamInRtf( m_richedit, 
R"({\rtf1
{\field{\*\fldinst {HYPERLINK "https://www.stackoverflow.com" }}{\fldrslt {stackoverflow}}}\par
Some other text\par
})" ); How can i do that

Comment: @SandeepKumar I believe you have to insert "https://" to make it a valid URL.

Comment: @zett42: Sorry if I was unclear. The question was if I have a url something like "https://stackoverflow.com" which is a valid URL stored in a string variable say urlstring. Now instead of writing {HYPERLINK "https://stackoverflow.com" } I wanted to use urlstring (something like  {HYPERLINK  urlstring } because my url comes dynamically and I use string to collect it

Comment: @SandeepKumar I still don't understand the problem. You could just break the RTF up and concatenate with your string variable? Like `StreamInRtf( m_richedit, 
R"({\rtf1
{\field{\*\fldinst {HYPERLINK ")" + urlstring + 
R"(" }}{\fldrslt {stackoverflow}}}\par
Some other text\par
})" );`